# Change Jenkins param variable value

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am new Jenkins pipeline. I wanted to change the value of a parameter given by the user during runtime. Below given is the script what I want to achieve.

```
pipeline{
agent any
parameters{
    string(name: 'Foo', defaultValue: 'abc-123, xyz-345' , description: '', trim: true)
}
stages{
    stage('Change'){
        steps{
            script{
                println "Foo"
                println Foo
                env.Foo = Foo.split(",").collect{val ->
                    return val.split("-")[0]
                }.join(",")
                
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
node{
   params.Foo = env.Foo
   println params.Foo
}
```

when I try with the above exmple I get this exception ***java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException***

Is there a way to solve this?

***Edit***

> **Input** :
> abc-123, xyz-345
>
> **Expected output** :
> abc, xyz

Comment: What is the input value of the parameter? What is expected output?

Comment: @zett42 Question is edited. Input and expected output is given now

Comment: With your code sample I get a different exception now: "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bb for class: WorkflowScript"

Comment: @zett42 Sorry for that it's corrected now

Answer (score 6):

`parameters` is an instance of `java`'s UnmodifiableCollection class, so it can't be changed.

Environment variables, however, *can* be changed, so you may want to try this:

```
stages{
    stage('Change'){
        steps{
            script{
                println "Foo"
                println params.Foo // makes clear what you are referring to
                env.FOO = params.Foo.split(",").collect{val ->
                    return val.split("-")[0]
                }.join(",")

            }
        }
    }
  }
}


node {
   // don't touch params: params.Foo = env.Foo

   // use only env.FOO to address your modified params
   println "env.FOO is ${env.FOO}"
}
```